# why when I input any number between 14 and 20, the output is incorrect?

Tags: c

'I need to calculate and print an upside down pascal triangle, so I wrote down 2 functions for factorial and for the nCr, and I have followed, the equation x! / (y! * (x - y)!)'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Factorial (int value)
{
if (value == 1 || value == 0)
{
    return 1;
}

return value*Factorial(value - 1);
}
int nCr(int value, int r)
{
return Factorial(value)/(Factorial(r) * Factorial(value - r));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int value, i, j, k;
char* p;
value = strtol(argv[1], &p, 10);
if (*p != '\0')
{
    return 1;
}
if (argc != 2)
{
    return 1;
}
if (value < 1 || value > 20)
{
    printf("Error: Please enter a value between 1 and 20 inclusively\n");
    return 1;
}
else
```

'The problem is supposed to be in the nested loops I guess'

```
 {
 for (i = value - 1; i >= 0; i--)
 {
    for (j = value - i; j > 0; j--)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
    for (k = 0; k <= i; k++)
    {
        printf("%d ", nCr(i, k));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because the factorial calculation for 13! and more, overflows `int`, and 21! and more will overflow `long long int`.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you a lot, I just made it long factorial and everything worked.

Comment: So please write an answer and mark it. This will help others with similar problems to find it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the declaration of the Factorial functions, as int type would overflow if the input is more than 13!, so we should declare the Factorial function as long, so that it does not overflow.